# What is wrong with this metaclass implementation?

Tags: python-2.7, metaclass

I am not saying that I need to, and I also saw this [How do I create a simple metaclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836263/how-do-i-create-a-simple-metaclass) but what's wrong with this simple implementation:

```
>>>class one(object):
       def __init__(self):
           class self:pass
```

After this I did:

```
>>>rat1=one()
>>>rat2=rat1()
TypeError: 'one' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Metaclasses derive from `type`, not `object`.

Comment: OK. So I replaced "object" with "type". But then it gives error in first time itself. TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments